# Applescript Choose file, filename

Tags: macos, applescript, filenames, osx-yosemite

What I'm trying to make is something like this:

```
set filename to (choose file)
display dialog "The name of the chosen file is: " & filename
```

But when I use that script it will return a path to the file something like .../.../.../.../nameoffile.jar. But what I want is that it will return the filename and not the path (so just only nameoffile.jar). Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for reading, please give an answer as soon as possible ;),

Jort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Finder Suite:

```
set chosenfile to (choose file)

tell application "Finder"
    display dialog "The name of the chosen file is: " & (name of chosenfile)
end tell
```